# Save data to Google Drive Spreadsheet using AJAX

Tags: javascript, ajax, google-api

I'm struggling to get it work for last couple of days. I'm writing a JS class which manipulates spreadsheets from user's Google Drive. So far I was able to create a spreadsheet and read an existing one. Now I have problem with saving data to existing spreadsheet.

I tried many ways, last one was like

```
jQuery.ajax({
            url: 'https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/cells/' + this.sheet + '/1/private/basic',
            type: 'put',
            contentType: "application/atom+xml",
            crossDomain:true,
            data: data,
            async: false,
            beforeSend: function(request)
            {
                request.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + token.Ka.access_token);

            },
            success: function(data)
            {
                console.log(data);
            }
        });
```

But this respond with **XMLHttpRequest cannot load XXXXXXX. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource**.

I was searching for an answer over and over again and I couldn't find it.

Comment: You probably can't use `async: false` with cross domain ajax calls.  In either case, you shouldn't develop with `async: false` as that just locks up the browser during the ajax call.

Comment: Thanks for a reply, however it's not it. After removing async:false I got the same results. It's something related to method, because when I do "get" - to get the content of the spreadsheet, it's all ok. The problem is with method put or post.

Comment: Does your data format match the `contentType`?  If you provide an `error` handler on the ajax call, what information does it provide?  Are there any hints in the debugger console?

Comment: With that error, it looks like you need to be using JSONP so the cross origin request will work.